# Python, List of Lists

Tags: python, list

I am currently having a problem, I'm wanting to add things to a list of list whilst creating the list of lists at the same time, for example here

```
Temp=[]
for j in range 10:
    for i in range 3:
       if j>1:
           Temp.append(i, i+1)
```

but this is giving me an error.

the output that i am looking for would be in the examples case
[[0, 1][1,2][2,3]]

Comment: You may append only one object. If you want to append a list, create it and pass it as a argument - `Temp.append([i, i+1])`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work: `temp = [[i, i+1] for i in range(3)]`

Comment: let me give a better example

Comment: @Adam: this is very good example. Take your time to learn some examples of list comprehension and you will soon find it really nice.

Answer (score 1):

To fix your solution, just add [brackets] around the list:

```
Temp=[]
for i in range(3):
    Temp.append([i, i+1])
```

If you don't mind tuples, consider this instead:

```
>>> zip(range(0,3), range(1,4))
[(0, 1), (1, 2), (2, 3)]
```